# Query for non-existent habtm record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

sorry for the beginner's question. 
I have habtm relationship between Assets and Projects. Assuming I'm looping thru all Assets I want to find all Projects not associated with this Asset, but this doesn't work:

```
Project.includes(:assets).where("assets.id != ?", asset.id)
```

what is the proper query?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all Projects not associated with a particular Asset, something like this should work (it's untested so adjust as needed):

```
Project.joins(:assets_projects).where("assets_projects.asset_id != ?", asset_id)
```

`asset_id` is the `id` of your Asset instance.

Also, you should not loop through the Assets to find all Projects associated with the iteration's current asset, that would mean too many database calls (it's the so called N+1 problem - a good explanation can be found eg [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)). To find all Projects not associated with any Asset with just one query, do this:

```
Project.find_by_sql(%(
  SELECT * FROM projects
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM assets_projects WHERE assets_projects.project_id = projects.id)
))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to find anything. I did  Project.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM projects WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM assets_projects WHERE assets_projects.asset_id != ?)", asset.id]). any clue?

Comment: I edited my answer based on the new version of your question. Hope it helps and don't hesitate to ask if it doesn't